# Power Bi Embedded A SKU (Resuming/Pausing)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a few questions regarding Power Bi Embedded as it does not really go into detail on the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity).

1. I have an idea of what it is, but in layman's terms, what exactly is a capacity?
2. In regards to Power Bi Embedded A SKU, you can pause and resume the capacity, however, when exactly would you pause the capacity for example? Also, what does pausing it hinder you from doing/seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A capacity is a defined amount of Power BI CPU and memory that you have access to, that you can use to run reports etc. However if your dataset or report is over the capacity limits it does not run/render. The PBI service will to some degree, expend to run the report on the shared service it runs on. There are limits to the normal PBI service, MS do not specify what they are. Capacities allow you to pay for a defined service and not worry about purchasing PBI licenses for each user that consumes reports.

For Power Bi Embedded pausing on the A SKU, it would not deliver the report to the front-end application that the reports are hosted in. You'll get a report not available and it will not render it. For example you can run a portal for a company during business hours, and turn it off outside those hours which will save you the costs for those paused hours.

If you access the report via the actual Power BI portal, you'll still be able to access the report via the workspace, if you have a Power BI Pro license for that tennant.